# How to create a safe call wrapper for RxJava functions in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

Pasted below is a piece of code from Google's [Plaid](https://github.com/android/plaid) app which wraps suspend functions and safely executes network operations. What changes need to be made to make it work with RxJava functions rather than Coroutines and wait for the network result, any help is appreciated.

```
/**
 * Wrap a suspending API [call] in try/catch. In case an exception is thrown, a [Result.Error] is
 * created based on the [errorMessage].
 */
suspend fun <T : Any> safeApiCall(call: suspend () -> Result<T>, errorMessage: String): Result<T> {
    return try {
        call()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // An exception was thrown when calling the API so we're converting this to an IOException
        Result.Error(IOException(errorMessage, e))
    }
}
```

Usage example in *ProductHuntRemoteDataSource.kt:*

```
class ProductHuntRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(private val service: ProductHuntService) {

    /**
     * Load Product Hunt data for a specific page.
     */
    suspend fun loadData(page: Int) = safeApiCall(
            call = { requestData(page) },
            errorMessage = "Error loading ProductHunt data"
    )

    private suspend fun requestData(page: Int): Result<GetPostsResponse> {
        val response = service.getPostsAsync(page)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val body = response.body()
            if (body != null) {
                return Result.Success(body)
            }
        }
        return Result.Error(IOException("Error loading ProductHunt data " +
                "${response.code()} ${response.message()}"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd not convert this code line-by-line into an rxjava equivalent. A better approach imo would be to write your custom retrofit calladapterfactory for rxjava that handles the errors and passes the error back as throwables in error stream or as sealed classes in normal stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make this work with RxJava by converting your observables to suspending functions using the `awaitFirst()` or `await()` (for Single) extension functions. You need to use the [RxJava](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2) extensions.

Edit:

you can write an extension function on your observables to do something similar, but not identical.

Here's a possible solution

```
fun <T> Observable<Result<T>>.safeCall(errorMessage: String, block: (Result<T>) -> Unit): Disposable =
    subscribe({ response: Result<T> ->
        if (response.isSuccess && response.body != null) {
            block(Result.Success(response.body))
        } else {
            block(Result.Error(IOException(errorMessage)))
        }
    }, { throwable ->
        block(Result.Error(IOException(errorMessage, throwable)))
    })
```

you would call this on an observable like this

```
val disposable = myObservable.safeCall("Error message") { result ->
    // TODO: handle result
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Francesc . Is there any way I could do it without suspend modifier? Because I wanna do it in a pure RxJava way and as far as I know suspend functions were created to help execute coroutines, maybe?!